# Showing that $X$ is dense in $C[0,1]$ with $\|f\|_{1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $X =\{f \in C[0,1] : f(0)=0 \}$. My effort: We wish to show that $\overline{X} = C[0,1]$, i.e., that every element in $C[0,1]$ is the limit of a sequence in $\overline{X}$. So I take an arbitrary $f \in C[0,1]$. We want to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_{n}-f\|_{1}=0$ for some $f_{n}$ in $X$. We have that

$\|f_{n} - f\|_{1} = \int_{0}^{1}|f(t)-f_{n}(t)|dt.$

And so....? I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Just to be on the same page: You want to find functions $f_n$ in $X$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \|f_n-f\|_1=0$.

Comment: @azif00 Yes, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The key insight is that the $L^1$ norm of a bounded (say) function $f$ can be changed by an arbitrarily small amount if you modify $f$ on a very small set. You can consider functions $f_n$ that agree with $f$ on $[1/n, 1]$, for example.

Comment: $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} f(x), \ \ \ &\mathrm{for} \ 1/n\leq x \leq 1  \\ 0, \ \ \ &\mathrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ I was wondering whether this is what you're referring to?

Comment: @MATHBOI: Those functions certainly approach $f$ in $L^1$, and satisfy $f_n(0) = 0$, but the issue is they may not be continuous depending on what $f$ is, so there needs to be some more thought about how precisely to define $f_n$.

Comment: For example $$ f_n(x) = \begin{cases} f(x),& 1/n \leq x \leq 1,\\ f(1/n)n x,&  0\leq x <1/n\end{cases}. $$ This function is continuous (as $f_n(1/n)=f(1/n)n \cdot 1/n=f(1/n)$) and $f_n(0)=f(1/n)n \cdot 0=0$ and $$ \Vert f_n - f\Vert_{L^1} \leq \frac{2\Vert f \Vert_{L^\infty}}{n}.  $$

Comment: It will help you to draw a picture to understand the construction above, Severin essentially took your function and interpolated it linearly on the interval $[0, 1/n]$. The area of this region gives you your $L^1$ error, it is a triangle with height $f(1/n)$, length $1/n$. Hence by triangle inequality you get error $f(1/n) 1/(2n) + \|f\|_\infty (1/n)$. (Since $f$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$, the supremum norm is bounded.)

Comment: @DrewBrady Thanks for explaining my last comment. I forgot to give the geometric intuition.